# Use UITextField input to update proximityUUID.UUIDString between segues

Tags: ios, swift, segue

Newbie Question

I am trying to use the text entered by a user from the UITextField to update a variable in another Viewcontroller #2. I successfully added a segue in Viewcontroller #1 and can access the properties in Viewcontroller #2. However when I try to use the data from the UITextField to update the UUIDString stored in the region property I receive a "Cannot assign to property: 'UUIDString' is a get-only property" error. Below is my code from viewcontroller #1

```
import UIKit
```

class beaconDetailsViewController: UIViewController,UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet weak var beaconOne: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var beaconTwo: UITextField!




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let planVC = segue.destinationViewController as! PlanagramViewController
    planVC.region.proximityUUID.UUIDString = self.beaconOne.text!
}
```

}

This is the variable located in veiwcontroller #2 that I would like to update with the UITextField input received from viewcontroller#1

```
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
var region = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: NSUUID(UUIDString: "B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D")!, identifier: "Estimotes")
let image = [59502: UIImage(named: "Plan_P"),49397: UIImage(named: "Plan_M")]
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check apple documentation ([CLBeaconRegion](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLBeaconRegion_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLBeaconRegion/proximityUUID)) proximityUUID is read-only property. What you need to do is create a new CLBeaconRegion using the new UUID.

```
CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: NSUUID(UUIDString: UUID)!, identifier: identifierString)
```

Tip: If you already started monitoring on the previous CLBeaconRegion stop it before creating the new one.

Comment: I appreciate the reply. Question how would I go about creating a new CLBeaconRegion using the new UUID if the property is only read only? Sorry for the newbies question here.

Comment: In the "PlanagramViewController" you can create a variable to hold the NSUUID string and then on 'viewDidLoad' you create a new CLBeaconRegion like I posted above. Remember to check the input text on the Textfield to check if the UUID is indeed valid. A more normal way to create an UUID is using the NSUUID default initializer 'NSUUID()'.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Everything is working as expected. I followed your suggestion and created a new CLBeaconRegion in "viewDidLoad". Now my app is working as expected. I still have a ton to learn. Thanks again for your help.